# How to update my array of comments in reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have Posts and each post has comments. I created a component and fetched the post's comments. These comments are in array form. I mapped into the array and displayed the comments individually. The challenge I am having now is how to update the individual comments. I am using node.js and mongodb for the backend. I am new to all of these and wondering the way to handle this.
Everything works well when I tested via postman. I can update the comments. To update the comments, I need the comment Id of the comment I want to update. Remember, each comment sits in a post.
In my backend, the path to edit an individual comment is like this:

```
router.put("/posts/:id/comment/:commentId", async (req, res) =>{
  //my codes
 }
```

How to get the comment's id in react is my challenge now and how to fetch the value of each comment so that I can update it. Here are my codes:

```
 export default function Comments() {
 const PF = "http://localhost:5000/images/";
 const {user} = useContext(Context)
 const location = useLocation()
 const path = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
 const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);// to fetch the comments for individual post
 const [updateComment, setUpdateComment] = useState(false);//for change edit mode
 const [commentdescription2, setCommentDescription] = useState("")
```

I fetched the comments for individual posts here:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const getPost = async () =>{
        try{
             const response = await axios.get("/posts/"+path )
             setComments(response.data.comments) //array of comments
          

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
   getPost()
}, [path])
```

The function that I tried to write to update the comments. I need the id of the comment to be able to update it to the database:

```
const handleCommentUpdate = async (id) =>{
const commentId = comments.map((singleId) => singleId._id ==id)

try{
    await axios.put("/posts/"+ path + "/comment" + commentId, {
         author: user._id, 
         commentdescription:  commentdescription2,
    })
     window.location.replace("/")
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
}
```

I mapped into the array of comments and displayed them here:

```
 return (
    <div className="comment">
        <h5 className='users-comment'>Users comments</h5>
            {comments.map((singleComment, index)=>{
                //console.log(singleComment)
                const {author, commentdescription, _id, createdAt} = singleComment
                
                return(
                    <>

                        {updateComment == _id ? //toggles comment into edit mode

                         <div className='comment-div' key={_id} >
        
                    <textarea className='comment-wrapper' type='text' 
                    onChange={(e) => setCommentDescription(e.target.value)} value={commentdescription2}>

                    </textarea>
                    <button className='comment-btn'onClick={handleCommentUpdate(_id)}>Update Post</button>
                    </div>
                        :
                         <div className='displayed-comments'key={_id}>
                            
                            <div className="commentPic">
                                
                                <img className="user-pics" src={PF + singleComment.author.profilePicture} alt="" />
                                  
                            </div>
                            <div className="comment-info">
                                <div className="comment-author-div">
                                    <div className='comment-author-date-info'>
                                        <h4 className="comment-author">{singleComment.author.username}</h4>
                                         <p className="comment-date">{new Date(singleComment.createdAt).toDateString()}
                                            </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="comment-edit-delete-div">
                                         <i className="singlePostIcon fas fa-edit" onClick={() => setUpdateComment(_id)}  ></i>
                                            <i className="singlePostIcon far fa-trash-alt"  ></i>

                                    </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                                <p className="comment-content">{singleComment.commentdescription}</p>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                        }
                         </>
                )
          
            })}

    </div>
)
```

Error message that I got when I tried using the function that I wrote about is :

```
Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

Is there a way out of this? Thanks

Comment: You miss a slash after `/comment`, and `commentId = comments.map` returns an array, probably not what you want. And another typo: `onClick={handleCommentUpdate(_id)}` should be `onClick={() => handleCommentUpdate(_id)}` or related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass prop `onClick` a function. So you should update `onClick` like this.

```
onClick={() => handleCommentUpdate(_id)}
```

And you have the `id` of comment when you call `handleCommentUpdate`. So you just use it with you logic

```
const handleCommentUpdate = async (id) => {

  try {
    await axios.put("/posts/" + path + "/comment" + id, {
      author: user._id,
      commentdescription: commentdescription2,
    });
    window.location.replace("/");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks, mate. Do you by chance know how I can also grab the value of the comment I clicked to update? Currently, once I click on the edit button, it changes to update mode. That is okay but it comes without the current content inside the comment box. That means I am not fetching the value. I think it is possible to get the value and edit it.